# System freezes immediately on suspending, where do I investigate?

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, sleep, xfce, suspend

I've just tried to suspend to RAM (i.e. sleep) my newly installed Xubuntu 19.10 machine, a Lenovo S340 Ideapad with a replaced SSD. Upon pressing suspend while logged in, the system freezes instantly. The screen does not go black and even after half an hour, the machine accepts no inputs other than the classic REISUB combo. I can't even move the mouse or change tty. This happens whenever I attempt to suspend, even with `systemctl suspend` and `xfce4-session-logout --suspend`. Strangest of all, **this does not occur on the same OS's Live Disk**.

**Where can I investigate the cause of this problem?** kern.log shows the entry `PM: suspend entry (deep)` at what looks like the appropriate time, but nothing comes before this other than what I was doing many minutes before and nothing comes after until the reboot has started. On the other hand, syslog.log shows more activity, and I have reproduced this below. Everything before and after the given point in time is too far out to be relevant:

```
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3612] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC whoopsie[1521]: [22:55:17] offline
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3616] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC kernel: [ 8812.324175] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd-sleep[16039]: Suspending system...
```

`journalctl` is similarly unhelpful:

```
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3612] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC whoopsie[1521]: [22:55:17] offline
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3616] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd-sleep[16039]: Suspending system...
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
-- Reboot --
```

As for solving this problem, nothing that I've seen on AskUbuntu or elsewhere online has worked:

- Blacklisting Intel modules such as mei has changed nothing of relevance.
- To my knowledge, I have no NVDIA modules to blacklist. In fact, I don't even have any options to install the drivers on the Additional Drivers menu. If there's an easy way to double-check, please comment.
- `lsmod | grep nouveau` suggests that I'm not running the notoriously buggy nouveau module.
- `apt list --installed | grep light` suggests that I'm not running the buggy lightlocker package.
- I am already using lightdm, so gdm can't be to blame.
- It has been suggested that this could be an ACPI issue, but I don't know how to approach that. As suggested by [Raffa](https://askubuntu.com/users/968501/raffa), I have placed my `dmesg | grep -i acpi` output [here](https://pastebin.com/WqdgDmpE). Apparently `[ 0.259633] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug` and `[    1.045638] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)` are cause for concern, but I do not know how to address them.
- `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` returns `s2idle [deep]`. I believe that this is the expected result.
- Making changes to Grub's GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT settings for the PCIe connection to my SSD has done nothing. I have tried many other suggestions for changing Grub's settings, but I've failed to keep a log of them.
- Editing SuspendState in /etc/systemd/sleep.conf has done nothing.
- Changing to older kernels, even as far back as 5.0.21-050021.201906040731 or as far forward as 5.3.0-18.19+1, has changed nothing.
- I am aware of [some similar bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774950) in some 4.x kernels, but I'm under the impression that they've been patched in the 5.x kernels, so they shouldn't be relevant.
- Lenovo is giving me contradictory dates for when the latest BIOS update was released, but my version number (ALCN28WW(V2.05)) matches theirs and the release date that `sudo dmidecode` gives me matches the date that's in their readme (November 25th 2019, contrary to their website's claim of December 16th 2019).

Comment: You might look for answers in http://askubuntu.com as well; please, however, do not double-post.

Comment: @K7AAY My search engine pointed there, but nothing helped or matched my problem. In fact, most info seems outdated. For example, pm-suspend is a thing of the past.

Comment: Even a blind pig finds an acorn now and then. Good that you checked. Good luck.

Comment: Have you tested to see if it is supported ? http://manpages.org/pm-is-supported

Comment: Also, "pm-aciton" http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pm-action.8.html

Comment: What type of machine are you running? Also, there is an _AskUbuntu_ page (don't know if you came across it, 2019) __waltinator__ has a good script there you might want to try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199148/ubuntu-19-10-freeze-when-waking-from-suspension

Comment: @vssher To the best of my awareness, pm stuff is defunct. I don't even have pm-utils installed. As for my machine, it's a Lenovo Ideapad S340.

Comment: Ever see this state: SuspendState=freeze (Note, that it is all Power Management to me) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html

Comment: @vssher Everything in my etc/systemd/sleep.conf file is commented out and I lack all three sleep.conf.d directories.

Comment: @vssher Editing sleep.conf to have SuspendState=freeze changes nothing.

Comment: I was simply asking if that was a setting which was being used in .conf file _SuspendState=freeze_ I thought maybe you should set this to _suspend_ Hope you find your answer(s).

Comment: There are endless problems with Ubuntu suspend. Check all measures mentioned in the following and add to your post: [post1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882843/system-freeze-after-suspend), [post2](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Suspend-resume-problems-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/6072410), [post3](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395562), [post4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1832960).

Comment: @harrymc Should I follow those posts even if the problems don't match mine, for example, those that only have issues in waking?

Comment: Better be selective, although it's hard to say if the same problem cannot have different symptoms.

Comment: @harrymc I've been through those links and made the relevant edits. Sadly, I've made no progress.

Comment: I found a new [BIOS update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s340-15api/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI). I suggest verifying suitability by entering your serial number or using Automatic Driver Update. But I'm unsure if Linux is supported.

Comment: @harrymc My BIOS is already up to date. Will edit to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking Into your `dmesg | grep -i acpi` output I can see what suggests that this is an ACPI issue. In particular, this:

```
[    1.045638] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
[    1.045676] acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
```

> [WMI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/WMI):
>
> Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is a complex set of
>   proprietary extensions to the Windows Driver Model that provides an OS
>   interface to allow instrumented components to provide information and
>   notifications.

This actually means that your machine was originally manufactured for Windows OS and although Ubuntu and other Linux distributions will mimic the Windows OS calls to the BIOS using different mechanisms amoung which [WMI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/WMI), there are times when this transaction is unsuccessful on ether ends and such issues happen.

The issues caused by this can range from just suspend issues to WiFi, Ethernet, battery, hard drives, SSDs and others.

Some of these issues appear with certain Linux kernels and disappear with others. They might differ but, are unlikely to disappear completely until the communication between system BIOS and the kernel is fixed. The ideal fix is a BIOS update from the manufacturer that addresses this issue.

What you can do besides that is to experiment with the hardware ie. the SSD and change the graphics drivers to open source or proprietary until the machine is stable. Also Upgrade to the next release of Ubuntu that comes next month as it might provide better support for your machines BIOS.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this here because it is too long for the comment section and it is in the format of the original page, except for the BOLD, that is mine.

> Immediately before entering system suspend and/or hibernation
>   systemd-suspend.service (and the other mentioned units, respectively)
>   **will run all executables in /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/** and **pass
>
>   two arguments to them.** The first argument will be "pre", the second
>   either "suspend", "hibernate", or "hybrid-sleep" **depending on the
>
>   chosen action**.  **Immediately after leaving system suspend** and/or
>   hibernation the same executables are run, but the first argument is
>   now "post". All executables in this directory are executed in
>   parallel, and execution of the action is not continued until all
>   executables have finished.

Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-sleep.8.html

Maybe you should *not* be commenting out items.

I ran a search for **/etc/systemd/sleep.conf** here at the sister site, with many [results](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%2Fetc%2Fsystemd%2Fsleep.conf).

Comment: Nothing in my /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ directory has commented out lines.