# How do I check if suspending is turning off my SSD?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, sleep, suspend

I'm having [some trouble suspending](https://superuser.com/q/1524979/865660) on Xubuntu 19.10. Given that, prior to a REISUB reboot, nothing is written to syslog.log after the lines below and that I'm being robbed of the ability to interact with my frozen machine (short of REISUB) after hitting suspend, I suspect that suspending is turning off my SSD. How can I check this?

syslog.log output:

```
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC whoopsie[1521]: [22:55:17] offline
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3616] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC kernel: [ 8812.324175] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd-sleep[16039]: Suspending system...
```