# Does swap size have any relevance to suspend to RAM?

Tags: memory, power-management, swap, xubuntu, suspend

I'm having [some trouble suspending my Xubuntu 19.10 machine](https://superuser.com/q/1524979/865660) and I've recently heard a suggestion that I might need more swap. Currently I have about 1GB of swap for 8GB of RAM, which I've heard is a little low despite usage of an SSD. However, I still find this suggestion a bit strange - why would suspending to RAM use my swap space? Isn't that only an issue for suspend to disk? This has forced me to ask my question - does swap size have any relevance to suspend to RAM?

Comment: RAM is always backed by swap. I suggest having swap equal to RAM.

Comment: @harrymc Even on an SSD? That sounds damaging.

Comment: "Backed by" means "only used if necessary".

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq explains swap sizing and options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq explains swap sizing and options. For a system with 8GB of RAM, it recommends 3GB unless you have added Hibernation after installation, in which case 11GB is recommended.

Using swap space is much slower than direct access into RAM, so reducing swappiness may help improve performance. The default after installation is 60; I would reduce it in small chunks (30, then 15) to see how your system and its apps behave with changes. this command will change swappiness only until you reboot:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=30
```

Once you have the optimal number, then make the change permanent by editing the swappiness value declared in

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```