# If I can't suspend an SSD-using machine, how should I conserve power when I'm not using it?

Tags: linux, ssd, sleep, power-management, suspend

I'm having [some trouble suspending my Xubuntu 19.10 machine](https://superuser.com/q/1524979/865660) that only uses an SSD for storage. However, I still want to be able to save power when I'm not using the system. How can I do this? Below are the ideas that I've had so far and why they're not good:

1. Turn the brightness down and lock it. This is currently what I'm doing, but it doesn't save much more power than simply walking away from the machine.
2. Sleep it, i.e. suspend to RAM. As above, I can't do this because I can't get my machine to suspend. This probably also rules out suspend to both.
3. Hibernate it, i.e. suspend to disk. I would, but to my knowledge that's ill-advised when your only form of storage is an SSD.
4. Turn it off. That's great for saving power, but not so great for when I want to resume from where I left off.
5. Hibernate it, but suspend to some disk other than your SSD. That would probably work, but I'm not plugging in an external hard drive whenever I want to leave my machine and there's no room in this laptop to install a new internal drive.

Do I have any other options? After all, it seems like suspending issues are common on many Linux systems.

Comment: What makes you think hibernation is bad on a SSD? I really like to see some evidence for that. To my knowledge that makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Tonny It's a lot of writes. That why a lot of modern OSs have hibernate disabled by default.

Comment: Windows 10, which is probably the most common modern OS, does hybrid sleep/hibernate by default. And modern SSD's (anything post 2015-2016) are far more tolerant for writes than the older ones. And Hibernate typically writes a fairly large file in a single pass which is not that bad from the SSD perspective. Write-wear is simply no longer a concern for most users for the life-time of the SSD.

Comment: "Suspend" [is not hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3369/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-suspend) and is only a stupid replacement term for ACPI ***sleep***.  Your inability to sleep (a basic [ACPI function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)) is one of the pieces Linux has never seemed to get right.  I have one linux box that is great suspend/resume over and over.. one (different brand) wont come out of sleep mode without a full ACPI reset.

Comment: You should fix the Xubuntu installation. Don't worry about the SSD, it can do much more than you think.

Comment: @harrymc Believe me, I'm trying.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The second answer to your linked question disagrees.