# Lenovo laptop seems to hibernate and won't boot

Tags: linux, boot, debian, lenovo-laptop, hibernate

My problem is about my lenovo ideapad S340.
I installed debian on it 2 years ago without any issue.
During these 2 years, i tested many things with it, and i had a problem of boot. 
My computer was sometimes freezing on grub just after i pressed enter to select my system. 
I was planning on formatting my laptop, so i did it, but i have the same issue.
I tried many things, and here is what i tried/found :

- My laptop seems to "hibernate". To manage to boot, i need to plug my AC charger, press the power button about 20 seconds. When i do this, grub shows up, i keep the power button pressed and the computer shuts down with a little noise. Then i can boot without any problem (until y shutdown the laptop).
- I tried to disable all the hibernations process with `systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target` without success.
- My computer seems to have a problem with the clocksource, sometimes it stays stuck to "swiched to clocksource tsc" (can sometimes be fixed with the noapic option in grub).
- I need private drivers to use my computer (ath10k).
- My bios is almost empty, i don't have any power tab in it (i tried to flash it but didn't found the right cap file, even with https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/mo/fr/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s340-15api/downloads/driver-list (i don't find any cap file when using innoextract).
- There is weird behavior when i try to boot with my AC or usb devices plugged.

While using my laptop, i recently had this message from the kernel: 
`Nov 13 14:27:02 Debian kernel: [ 5517.506780] Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 2d on CPU 6. Nov 13 14:27:02 Debian kernel: [ 5517.506781] Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled? Nov 13 14:27:02 Debian kernel: [ 5517.506782] Dazed and confused, but trying to continue` 
Return of `uname -a` : Linux Debian 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks you for reading my post.

EDIT: Experienced a new bug: i closed my laptop yesterday and when i reopened it today, it was off, but when i pressed the power button, the power light was blinking. Linux started to boot and then got stuck, [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODz5R.jpg) 
I did not managed to make it boot again, but i will post the output of `dmesg | grep -i acpi` when i will be able to. 
(EDIT 2: I managed to boot with the noapic option in GRUB.) 
I called the lenovo hotline, and they told me that installing windows, flashing the bios, adjusting the power parameters from windows and reboot on linux could fix my issue, because the power management of the bios can now only be modified from windows for "security reasons". I will keep you up to date.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dmesg | grep -i acpi`?

Comment: @J.Mini [Here is the result](https://imgur.com/a/k7eT6Ri). Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I own the same laptop and [have had similar issues in the past](https://superuser.com/q/1524979/). Updating to Xubuntu 20.04 fixed the issues for me, but you might find some stuff of value on that link.

It's not a quick fix, but I sincerely expect that the best fix is to wait for new kernal versions.

Comment: Thank you for your anwnser. I will try to update my computer to testing or unstable, and i'll wait for a new kernel update.